# Stream data between two PCs in C#, without IP-network

Tags: c#, windows, usb, firewire

For a project I'm doing I need to stream data from one windows computer to another *without using the IP-network* (including cross-linked ethernet cable, for instance).

The streaming application should be written in C#, although I can probably get away with a C# wrapper, if necessary.

I've considered USB link cables and Firewire, but so far I've failed to find any drivers for sending custom data via these.

Did someone try this before, or know which way to go? Any suggestion would be appreciated!

**Edit** The speed of the connection should preferably be close to fast Ethernet (100Mbps). For the mentioned cables this should be no problem (USB 2.0 is 480Mbps, Firewire800 is 800Mbps).

Comment: Good question, will be interesting to see the answer on it.

Comment: Long ago we used NULL-modem serial cables :) But seriously why you don't want to build ip connection with usb cable? I may be wrong, but I think windows can do that out of box. Couple of years ago Iv'e done this with IEEE1394, but i think the same can go with USB

Comment: Ha ha! I just thought of creating a complex, noise-resistant protocol working over audio cable then connect audio output of one comp to another an vice versa. And serialize/deserialize data to audio streams...

Comment: @David If I'm informed correctly, IP over firewire is no longer supported (by default) since Vista, but I think it should work over USB. Nevertheless, I'm not allowed to use any IP traffic. Why? Well, customer is king ;-)

Comment: What are your requirements for the streaming performance?

Comment: http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBtoUSB.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose a different approach, but for those interested, I can share the results of my research. I found 3 potential solutions, at different cost levels.

1. *Using a USB link cable*. This requires a USB 2.0 bridge/link cable ($15 - $40, depending on the quality) and a wrapper around the standard Windows driver. This wrapper can be implemented using [LibUsbDotNet](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net).
2. *Using FireWire*. This requires a standard FireWire cable. A custom driver should be implemented, for which I found only one SDK called [FireAPI](http://www.unibrain.com/products/driverapi/fireapi.html). The API is *very* low-level and in-depth knowledge of FireWire is a must. The licence fee for this SDK is $450.
3. *Using reflective memory*. This requires two custom PCI cards and a corresponding wire. The PCI cards will automatically copy a predefined region of RAM memory to each other, with very low latency. This approach is definitely the easiest, but also most costly. The cheapest variant I found, by [Dolphinics](http://www.dolphinics.com/products/embedded-system-reflective-memory.html), still costs about $1.500 for the entire solution.